# dplyr mutate returning NA wheras sapply isn't with strsplit

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the kaggle titanic dataset where the column Cabin is class character. I used the function shown below to get the first element of each Cabin.

```
sapply(df$Cabin,function(x) strsplit(x,NULL)[[1]][1])

Cabin    deck
 NA      NA
 C85     C
 NA      NA
 C123    C
 NA      NA
 E46     E
```

However when I use dplyr's mutate to achieve the same task I just get a column of NAs for deck. These are the functions I tried with mutate and both returned just NAs.

```
df %>% mutate(deck = ifelse(is.na(Cabin),Cabin, strsplit(Cabin,NULL)[[1]][1]))
```

and

```
df %>% mutate(deck = strsplit(Cabin,NULL)[[1]][1])
```

Is there something wrong with mutate or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer has to do with what object `strsplit` is acting on when you call it the two different ways.

From `strsplit`'s documentation, it returns

> A list of the same length as x, the i-th element of which contains the
>   vector of splits of x[i].

When you call `sapply(df$Cabin,function(x) strsplit(x,NULL)[[1]][1])`, `strsplit` acts separately on each element of the vector `df$Cabin`, so it's as if you're calling:

```
strsplit(df$Cabin[1], NULL)[[1]][1]
# [1] NA
strsplit(df$Cabin[2], NULL)[[1]][1]
# [1] C
...
```

In contrast, `mutate` is calling `strsplit` on the entire vector, so it's as if you're calling `strsplit(df$Cabin, NULL)`

```
strsplit(df$Cabin, NULL)
# [[1]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C" "8" "5"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "C" "1" "2" "3"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "E" "4" "6"
```

As we can see from the output, `strsplit(df$Cabin, NULL)[[1]][1]` is `NA`, so that gets populated everywhere.

To get the desired output, you could use `substring` since the info you want is always in the same position.

```
df %>%
  mutate(deck = substring(Cabin, 1, 1))
 # Cabin deck
 #  <NA> <NA>
 #   C85    C
 #  <NA> <NA>
 #  C123    C
 #  <NA> <NA>
 #   E46    E
```